# skip value in for loop if it = 0 c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

how to skip writing the value to the file if it = 0 in my calculator program

Procedure that writes the array into a file

```
 public void SaveArrayToFile()

        {
            int count;
            var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:/calc/calculations.txt",false);
            for (count = 0; count <= Results.Length -1 ; count++)
            {
                if (Results[count] == 0)
                {
                    // problem
                }
                writer.Write(Results[count]);
                writer.WriteLine();
            }
            writer.Dispose();
```

Any help would be valued

Comment: Use `else`, if your loop has a large body `continue`s will make it unreadable

Comment: What do you want it to do if `Results[count] == 0`? Should it write an empty row to the file? Should it write a special value that means 'no data present'? Should it skip the row entirely? Skipping the row entirely is easy with the `continue` keyword, but if these results need to be read in by another program, that may not work.

Comment: Instead of saying `writer.Dispose();` in the end, you should use a `using` statement: `using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:/calc/calculations.txt", false)) { for ... }`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either

```
if (Results[count] == 0)
{
    continue;
}
writer.WriteLine(Results[count]);
```

or even simpler

```
if (Results[count] != 0)
{
    writer.WriteLine(Results[count]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i needed i didn't know about continue

Answer (score 6):

That's exactly what the [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement is for.

```
if (Results[count] == 0)
{
    continue;
}
```

You could also solve this problem using Linq:

```
foreach (var result in Results.Where(r => r != 0))
{
    writer.Write(result);
    writer.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (Results[count] != 0)
{
  writer.Write(Results[count]);
  writer.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `continue`

```
//your code

if (Results[count] == 0)
{
    continue;
}

//your code
```

**More ([Jump Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d96yfwee%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):**

- To terminate the loop use the `break` keyword.
- To escape the current iteration use `continue`

Answer (score 3):

simply:

```
if (Results[count] != 0)
{
       // Write it.
}
```